# (Z3Py) any limitations in functions declaring?

Tags: python, z3

Is there any limitations in functions declaring?

For example, this piece of code returning unsat.

```
from z3 import *

def one_op (op, arg1, arg2):
    if op==1:
        return arg1*arg2
    if op==2:
        return arg1-arg2
    if op==3:
        return arg1+arg2

    return arg1+arg2 # default

s=Solver()

arg1, arg2, result, unk_op=Ints ('arg1 arg2 result unk_op')

s.add (unk_op>=1, unk_op<=3)

s.add (arg1==1)
s.add (arg2==2)
s.add (result==3)
s.add (one_op(unk_op, arg1, arg2)==result)

print s.check()
```

How Z3Py interpret declared function? Is it just calling it some times or some hidden machinery also here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function call `one_op(unk_op, arg1, arg2)`, `unk_op` is a Z3 expression. Then, expressions such as `op==1` and `op==2` (in the definition of `one_op`) are also Z3 symbolic expressions. Since `op==1` is not the Python Boolean expression `False`. The function `one_op` will always return the Z3 expression `arg1*arg2`. We can check that by executing `print one_op(unk_op, arg1, arg2)`. Note that the `if` statements in the definition of `one_op` are Python statements.

I believe your true intention is to return a Z3 expression that contains conditional expressions. You can accomplish that by defining `one_op` as:

```
def one_op (op, arg1, arg2):
    return  If(op==1,
               arg1*arg2,
               If(op==2,
                  arg1-arg2,
                  If(op==3,
                     arg1+arg2,
                     arg1+arg2)))
```

Now, the command `If` builds a Z3 conditional expression. By using, this definition, we can find a satisfying solution. Here is the complete example:

```
from z3 import *

def one_op (op, arg1, arg2):
    return  If(op==1,
               arg1*arg2,
               If(op==2,
                  arg1-arg2,
                  If(op==3,
                     arg1+arg2,
                     arg1+arg2)))

s=Solver()

arg1, arg2, result, unk_op=Ints ('arg1 arg2 result unk_op')

s.add (unk_op>=1, unk_op<=3)
s.add (arg1==1)
s.add (arg2==2)
s.add (result==3)
s.add (one_op(unk_op, arg1, arg2)==result)

print s.check()
print s.model()
```

The result is:

```
sat
[unk_op = 3, result = 3, arg2 = 2, arg1 = 1]
```

Comment: Ah, so the function should return Z3 expression, it's like a expression constructor!